# WiShield 2.0 issue

Tags: web-services, network-programming, arduino

I am currently working on a project involving a [BlackWidow board](http://asynclabs.com/wiki/index.php?title=BlackWidow_1.0) that can establish a connection to the server, but cannot transmit data/receive acknowledgement or anything. For the moment we are trying to send a single byte. There are few examples, and most of them have the BlackWidow acting as a server. The examples where it it acting as a client will not work with us for whatever reason.

What could be the matter and are there some online resources that might help? Any help would be great!

Comment: I have BlackWidow as well, but I am using it as a server for the time being. So I dont have first hand experience with setting up the device as client. Did you try to inquire at asynclabs forum?

Comment: Have you built the WiShield library in webclient mode as documented [here](http://asynclabs.com/wiki/index.php?title=WebClient_sketch)?

Try to see if your BlackWidow is sending any data at all with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or the likes.